# Check vector of downloaded jpg and find missing id

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of downloaded jpg files. I want to check number of IDs of missing downloaded images.

length(id) > length(myfiles)

```
id <- c("1", "2", "3")
myfiles <- c("C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1.jpg",
             "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/3.jpg")
```

I want to get something like:

```
missing_id
[1] 2
```

Comment: Could do something like `setdiff(id, sub(".jpg", "", fixed = TRUE, basename(myfiles)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract the file number and `%in%` to check whether all values of `id` are present:

```
id[!id %in% sub("(?:.+/)(\\d+)\\.jpg?", "\\1", myfiles)]
# [1] "2"
```